# getIntent(), getStringExtra() are deprecated

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass strings from one activity to another.

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                String m = markerMap.get(marker.getId());

                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if(m.equals(name[i])) {
                        
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, CustomInfoWindowAdapter.class);
                        intent.putExtra("FOOD_BANK",name[i]);
                        intent.putExtra("STREET_ADDRESS",address[i]);
                        intent.putExtra("WEBSITE",website[i]);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
        });
```

That's the chunk of code that is supposed to send the strings to the other activity.

```
private void rendowWindowText(Marker marker, View view) {

Intent intent = getIntent();
        String foodBank = getStringExtra("FOOD_BANK");
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tvTitle.setText(foodBank);

        String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        String address = getStringExtra("STREET_ADDRESS");
        tvSnippet.setText(address);

        /*if(!title.equals("")) {
            tvTitle.setText(title);
        }*/
    }
```

This bit is what should be receiving the data but getIntent() and getStringExtra() are deprecated. I've tried surpressing the deprecation with `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` before the method. I've tried restarting Android Studio and my computer with no avail. I've tried `getActivity().getIntent();` and no luck either.

The message when I hover my cursor over the deprecated getIntent() is:

`Cannot resolve method 'getIntent' in 'CustomInfoWindowAdapter'`

Would really appreciate any ideas on how to fix this because I'm very new to Android Studio and Java in general.

Comment: `getStringExtra()` should be replaced with `intent.getStringExtra()`

Answer (score 2):

To get the data which u sent, use the following code :

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String foodBank = extras.getString("FOOD_BANK");
            String address = extras.getString("STREET_ADDRESS");
        }
```